# Children with the same key: Object.assign vs _.merge

Tags: reactjs, redux, lodash

I am wondering if I fully understand the difference between assign and merge in javascript. Whenever the following reducer updates the state I get the `Encountered two children with the same key` error

```
function updateKeyframes(state, action) {
  const { keyframeIds, props } = action.payload;

  const newKeyframes = _.map(keyframeIds, function(id) {
    return _.merge(state.keyframes[id], props);
  });

  return Object.assign({}, state, {
     keyframes: Object.assign({}, state.keyframes, newKeyframes)
  });
}
```

However, if I calculate newKeyframes in a different way the error disappears.

```
const newKeyframes = keyframeIds.reduce((memo, keyframeId) =>
Object.assign({}, memo, {
 [keyframeId]: Object.assign({}, state.keyframes[keyframeId], props)
}), {});
```

Why? What is going on here?

Comment: `_.merge` is recursive. It's difficult to see differences if you don't show us your data. Also `_.map` for objects does something very different that you expect. It maps values into an `array`. That means your `id` is not even an `id`and the result is not an object but an array.

Comment: You are correct, thank you for the help. I wanted to set state.keyframes to an object, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example `newKeyframes` is an array. In your second example `newKeyFrames` is an object. There is an obvious difference then in:

```
 Object.assign({}, state.keyframes, newKeyframes)
```

if `newKeyFrames` is an array, the key replacement won't probably go as expected.

Comment: Wound up creating my object using reduce:
const newKeyframes = _.reduce(keyframeIds, function(result, id) {
    result[id] = _.merge(state.keyframes[id], props);
    return result;
  }, {});